# Incomplete documentation on creating tags

Tags: support, tags, documentation

The [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (on Stack Overflow) on creating tags appears to be either wrong or incomplete.  Specifically, it states:

> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created.

however attempting to do this (at least for a tag with a similar name to an existing name) gives the error:

> You are attempting to create the tag [XXXXs]; however the tag [XXXX]
>   already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it
>   on meta.

[image: Error message image]

Comment: I'm confused.  Why is documentation incorrect?  The error message doesn't seem related to creating a tag but you trying to create a tag that already exists.  Can you share the tag you were trying to create?

Comment: What was the tag you tried to create? Perhaps you've hit upon one that has been blacklisted? I don't see why we need to complicate the help for those rare cases. The error message seems to provide sufficiently clear advice.

Comment: I was looking at creating the tag "sparks" (as relates to the pseudo language described in http://www.icodeguru.com/vc/10book/books/book1/toc.htm), which is distinct from the tag 'spark' (a Flex 4 architecture).

Comment: @borrible Ah, the system thinks you are trying to create a synonym (or have misspelled your tag). Automated filters are fun, aren't they? You should edit your question here to include the tags' names, as they are the reason for the issue. I'm afraid [sparks] isn't going to go through, how about [sparks-language] instead?

Comment: @Cody Gray - regarding complicating the help, I posted this question since - having tried creating a tag for the first time in three years - I hit an unexpected message which made me question whether the behaviour had changed.

Comment: @yannis - sparks-language seems absolutely fine

Comment: You entered a new tag in your question, and the system did interpret it as a request to create a new tag. That request was denied, but the documentation is correct, it's just missing the edge case that some tags can't be created because their name isn't accepted (too long, blacklisted, too close to an existing tag, invalid characters, …).